# pandas - why will left join introduce new values and a lot of duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, join

When performing an operation like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'idNo':[1,2,3], 'value_1':[0,1,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'idNo':[1,2,3], 'value_2':[1,1,0]})
merged_data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='idNo', how='left')
print(df1.shape)
print(merged_data.shape)
merged_data.duplicated(subset=['idNo']).sum()
```

How can it be that `merged_data.duplicated` will not be 0 (it is 0 for this minimal example)? And if it is > 0, can I safely drop duplicates? Is pandas joining via the index ans messing something up?

For my real data read from a CSV I see the problem that a lot of duplicated values will be introduced for such a left join operation, but do not understand why. Is it safe to simply drop the duplicates?

## edit

this basically only concatenates columns. Maybe there is a better operation in pandas which will not cause duplicates?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question. Is `merged_data` itself surprising to you? Can you be more clear as to what is surprising about `merged_data.duplicated`?

Comment: For me it is surprising that `merged_data` contains dupicates. As I only concatenate columns. Please also see the latest edit.

Comment: There are no duplicates in this example. The resulting DataFrame `merged_data` is 3 by 3 and the rows are all distinct. It doesn't sound like you want to be merging the DataFrames if this is not the result you want. I suggest you edit your question to include an example of what you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a duplicate `'idNo'` in one of your `df`s

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'idNo':[1,2,3], 'value':[0,1,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'idNo':[1,2,3,3], 'value':[1,1,0,1]})
merged_data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='idNo', how='left')
print(df1.shape)
print(merged_data.shape)
merged_data.duplicated(subset=['idNo']).sum()

(3, 2)
(4, 3)

1
```

This makes perfect sense!

Comment: I see will remove question as obviously not a great one.